# CakePHP(2.5.5) sessions in database

Tags: php, database, session, cakephp

I'm trying to save my sessions in the database. I made a table as per instructions and changed my config file. Sessions *are* saved, but when the server tries to retrieve them, it spews out `Fatal error: Call to a member function getColumnType() on a non-object in /lib/Cake/Model/Model.php on line 1426`. No session variables can be retrieved, even though they appear to be successfully saved in the database.

Any help? I have not tried this on any previous versions of CakePHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone stumbling on the same problem: **Do not name any of your tables or databases "data"!** Such a silly problem, took me way too much time.